# Estimating the error when fitting a curve with DCT and polyfit

Tags: matlab

I have a matlab script that performs curve fitting on a set of curves using polynomials of third, second and first order (using polyfit with the desired order) and also using DCT of 4,3 and 2 coefficients (invoking dct for the whole array and then truncating just the first 4,3 or 2 coeffs).

I'm able to get a graphical view of the accuracy of each curve fitting using polyval and idct for the 2 types of curve fitting, but I was wondering if there is any way of getting a numeric value of the accuracy that makes sense for both approaches (dct and polyfit).

I'm sure this is more a maths question rather than a Matlab question, but maybe there is some way to obtain a simple and elegant way in a array-based algorithm that I haven't thought of yet.

Thanks in advance for your comments!

EDIT: What about correlation? :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the cuve fitting tool there should be a residual that uses standard deviation. If you are interested in another way to do it maybe you should use rmse for the entire curve, scripting a function that does something like:

input args : y1 = (curve going to be fitted), y2 = (fitted curve)

1. For each value in y, sum up the difference y1-y2 squared
2. Divide with the number of entries
3. Provided you are now left with a number, return its square root

See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root-mean-square_deviation#Formula for more.

Comment: I thought of obtaining the correlation with corrcoef. Does the RMS provide in any way a better idea of how big the difference is between the 2 curves?

Comment: By the way, the function rms with an input y-y', being y' the fitted curve will provide the same RMS calculation element-wise.

Comment: This is the way we learned in experimental physics, but sure, whatever way suits you!
Yes, in matlab there are several way to do so since you are working with matrices, and using some linear algebra should do the trick nicely!